# Find the length of an array / comma separated string values in Quicksight Calculated Field

Tags: arrays, string, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

I have a column of sent_to_emails in my Quicksight Dataset. I want to calculate the number of values in this comma separated string i.e. split the string based on a delimiter and then calculate the number of values returned in array. Like;

"abc@abc.com,rec@rec.com,k12@12v.com" should return 3

I've searched a couple of string functions that are supported in AWS Quicksight but nothing is supporting the required results.